# Sas mainframe data filename older rec deletion

Tags: sas

```
DATA ML1;                 
INFILE CARDS;             
INPUT @1 FILENAME $CHAR10.
      @12 REFDT YYMMDD8.; 
CARDS;                    
LOAN_CREA 20/09/20        
LOAN_UPDT 18/09/20        
LOAN_MAIN 19/09/20        
 ;                         
RUN;      
DATA DEL;                                                    
SET ML1;                                                     
PUT @1 ' DELETE ' FILENAME;                                  
RUN;
```

Hi All plz look above code i am facing one issue i want to delete older filename not recent one kindly find below my requirement
**My Req is :
LOAN_UPDT

LOAN_MAIN**

Comment: Kindly respond any one for the above code issue plz

Comment: Please show us what you have and what you want, your question is unclear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sas mainframe deletion file between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64050232/sas-mainframe-deletion-file-between-two-dates)

Comment: Please do not re-post questions - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear what you are trying to do.  This will PUT a delete for all except the newest:

```
* Sort file to make newest the first;
Proc sort data=ml1;
 by refdt dsecending;

data _null_;
  set ml1; by refdt;
  if first.refdt then return;  * Ignore the first one (newest);
  put @1 ' DELETE' filename;
```